# Running a .net 4.0 application under a 2.0 site in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I have an IIS "site" set up with an app pool that uses .net 2.0. I have added a .NET "application" to the site that requires .net 4.0.

I set the app pool for that specific site to  use .net 4.0 but when I do I get a `500` error with Error Code: `0x800700c1`

Can I do this? Or am I trying to do the impossible?

Notes: I wanted to refrain from changing the app pool of the whole IIS site to use .NET 4.0 because there is a LOT of code to be tested if I do. I also can't add it as a separate site entirely because I run into cross origin issues.

Update: Even if I set up both app pool under .NET 4 I get the same error. I have to use the SAME app pool for both the site and the sub-app. I feel like this should not be a requirement.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Did you register .NET 4 with IIS? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: @ken - .net 4 works fine. If I create a new site and run it under .net 4 there is no problem (except for the cross origin, which is why I have to make it a sub-application)

Comment: upon further research it looks like I need to do the following: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770150 which means not inheriting certain settings from the child application, which is not preferable

Comment: @JohnSaunders - With all due respect, I feel like you posting that comment was more of a clutter than my "Thanks!", however, I'll refrain from preemptively thanking people for their help in the future.

Comment: @kralco626: that is the desired effect of posting the comment.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I'm quite aware of that. Just saying, you editing my post would have done the trick. Anyways, not sure there was really a consensus on that post about "Thanks", but more so about signatures and greetings. But anyways, I'll move on since this isn't the place to talk about this :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to `True` for the application pool for the .NET 4 sub-app and it worked while keeping the parent site with an app pool of .NET 2.

Haven't completely tested it, but so far it works.